# phpmyadmin frame contents not loading after port change, have changed PmaAbsoluteUri

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

I had phpmyadmin all set up and working on port 8080. I remember changing quite a few things but it was a while ago :( 
Due to ugly :8080s in the URL, I'm now changing everything back to port 80. the rest of the server after the port change works fine.

I've already changed PmaAbsoluteUri back to the non-port version.

I can load the index.php, the login part loads with images and I log in with root and password fine, meaning (I think) that mysql is working ok.

The index page loads from looking at the source, but the frames are blank.

When I change the address bar to point directly to the main.php or navigation.php they load ok, but without images.

I have a feeling I made a change to common.inc.php which I believe was something to do with images, but can't remember what!

I'm the queen of making stupid mistakes and spending the longest time on the most obvious ones, so even the most basic suggestions are welcome!

System is mac osX, server is tomcat (for the jsps), wordpress/phpmyadmin 3.5.8.2 run using quercus-4.0.37

Comment: If you think you made changes to the code but can't remember what they were, why don't you save your config.inc.php and download phpMyAdmin again? Is it possible your webserver is still trying to redirect some pages?

Comment: Did that and the same thing is happening. Perhaps theres something in mySql that stops it working?

Comment: Also, my page is not redirecting for phpmyadmin or any of my other webapps but the wordpress installations are - now I assume that once I get phpmyadmin working and I change the databases using UPDATE from localhost:8080 to localhost then that will stop that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after seeing some similar things going on for the newer versions of phpMyAdmin to do with a content-security problem in Safari, I commented out some lines in libaries/header_http.inc.php:

```
/*if (!$GLOBALS['cfg']['AllowThirdPartyFraming']) {
header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');
header("X-Content-Security-Policy: allow 'self' ;
options inline-script eval-script;
frame-ancestors 'self';
img-src 'self' data:");
if (PMA_USR_BROWSER_AGENT == 'SAFARI' && PMA_USR_BROWSER_VER < '6.0.0') { 
    header("X-WebKit-CSP: allow 'self'; options inline-script eval-script");
} else {     
    header("X-WebKit-CSP: default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'");
}*/
```

this seems to have worked - php index loading correctly with images. Not sure if I've just duffed up some major security though!